# Using numpy to efficiently convert 16-bit image data to 8 bit for display, with intensity scaling

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy

I frequently convert 16-bit grayscale image data to 8-bit image data for display. It's almost always useful to adjust the minimum and maximum display intensity to highlight the 'interesting' parts of the image.

The code below does roughly what I want, but it's ugly and inefficient, and makes many intermediate copies of the image data. **How can I achieve the same result with a minimum memory footprint and processing time?**

```
import numpy

image_data = numpy.random.randint( #Realistic images would be much larger
    low=100, high=14000, size=(1, 5, 5)).astype(numpy.uint16)

display_min = 1000
display_max = 10000.0

print(image_data)
threshold_image = ((image_data.astype(float) - display_min) *
                   (image_data > display_min))
print(threshold_image)
scaled_image = (threshold_image * (255. / (display_max - display_min)))
scaled_image[scaled_image > 255] = 255
print(scaled_image)
display_this_image = scaled_image.astype(numpy.uint8)
print(display_this_image)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are doing is [halftoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) your image.

The methods proposed by others work great, but they are repeating a lot of expensive computations over and over again. Since in a `uint16` there are at most 65,536 different values, using a look-up table (LUT) can streamline things a lot. And since the LUT is small, you don't have to worry that much about doing things in place, or not creating boolean arrays. The following code reuses Bi Rico's function to create the LUT:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

rows, cols = 768, 1024
image = np.random.randint(100, 14000,
                             size=(1, rows, cols)).astype(np.uint16)
display_min = 1000
display_max = 10000

def display(image, display_min, display_max): # copied from Bi Rico
    # Here I set copy=True in order to ensure the original image is not
    # modified. If you don't mind modifying the original image, you can
    # set copy=False or skip this step.
    image = np.array(image, copy=True)
    image.clip(display_min, display_max, out=image)
    image -= display_min
    np.floor_divide(image, (display_max - display_min + 1) / 256,
                    out=image, casting='unsafe')
    return image.astype(np.uint8)

def lut_display(image, display_min, display_max) :
    lut = np.arange(2**16, dtype='uint16')
    lut = display(lut, display_min, display_max)
    return np.take(lut, image)


>>> np.all(display(image, display_min, display_max) ==
           lut_display(image, display_min, display_max))
True
>>> timeit.timeit('display(image, display_min, display_max)',
                  'from __main__ import display, image, display_min, display_max',
                   number=10)
0.304813282062
>>> timeit.timeit('lut_display(image, display_min, display_max)',
                  'from __main__ import lut_display, image, display_min, display_max',
                  number=10)
0.0591987428298
```

So there is a x5 speed-up, which is not a bad thing, I guess...

Comment: Very nice! This is the sort of thing I wouldn't have come up with on my own.

Comment: Beautiful and elegant solution!

Comment: Something interesting, and as expected, if you use cupy, it doesn't matter, both functions run at same speed. I'll write below.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce memory usage, do the clipping in-place and avoid creating the boolean arrays.

```
dataf = image_data.astype(float)
numpy.clip(dataf, display_min, display_max, out=dataf)
dataf -= display_min
datab = ((255. / (display_max - display_min)) * dataf).astype(numpy.uint8)
```

If you keep your clipping limits as integer values, you can alternately do this:

```
numpy.clip(image_data, display_min, display_max, out=image_data)
image_data-= display_min
datab = numpy.empty_like(image_data)
numpy.multiply(255. / (display_max - display_min), image_data, out=datab)
```

Note: that a temporary float array will still be created in the last line before the `uint8` array is created.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `clip`.

Comment: I wonder if using `numpy.multiply` with the `out` argument set to image_data works equivalently? I know it's trying to write float data to a uint16 array, but that might be what we want anyway?

Comment: The idea being, to eliminate the float array.

Comment: That's a great point.  I edited the second version in my answer to use the `out=` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid casting the image to float, you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np

def display(image, display_min, display_max):
    # Here I set copy=True in order to ensure the original image is not
    # modified. If you don't mind modifying the original image, you can
    # set copy=False or skip this step.
    image = np.array(image, copy=True)

    image.clip(display_min, display_max, out=image)
    image -= display_min
    image //= (display_min - display_max + 1) / 256.
    image = image.astype(np.uint8)
    # Display image
```

Here an optional copy of the image is made in it's native data type and an 8 bit copy is make on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I found on crossvalidated board in comments under this solution
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808/277040

Basically for converting from uint16 to uint8 algorithm looks like this

```
a = (255 - 0) / (65535 - 0)
b = 255 - a * 65535
newvalue = (a * img + b).astype(np.uint8)
```

A generalized version would look like this

```
def convert(img, target_type_min, target_type_max, target_type):
    imin = img.min()
    imax = img.max()

    a = (target_type_max - target_type_min) / (imax - imin)
    b = target_type_max - a * imax
    new_img = (a * img + b).astype(target_type)
    return new_img
```

e.g.

`imgu8 = convert(img16u, 0, 255, np.uint8)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old tread, but we now have cupy with gpu acceleration.
With cupy is always faster (both methods from Jaime great comment run at closer speed) with cupy.

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
import timeit
rows, cols = 768, 1024
image = np.random.randint(100, 14000,
                             size=(1, rows, cols)).astype(np.uint16)
display_min = 1000
display_max = 10000

def display(image, display_min, display_max): # copied from Bi Rico
    # Here I set copy=True in order to ensure the original image is not
    # modified. If you don't mind modifying the original image, you can
    # set copy=False or skip this step.
    image = np.array(image, copy=True)
    image.clip(display_min, display_max, out=image)
    image -= display_min
    np.floor_divide(image, (display_max - display_min + 1) / 256,
                    out=image, casting='unsafe')
    return image.astype(np.uint8)

def lut_display(image, display_min, display_max) :
    lut = np.arange(2**16, dtype='uint16')
    lut = display(lut, display_min, display_max)
    return np.take(lut, image)


def displaycp(image2, display_min, display_max): # copied from Bi Rico
    # Here I set copy=True in order to ensure the original image is not
    # modified. If you don't mind modifying the original image, you can
    # set copy=False or skip this step.
    image2 = cp.array(image2, copy=True)
    image2.clip(display_min, display_max, out=image2)
    image2 -= display_min
    cp.floor_divide(image2, (display_max - display_min + 1) / 256,
                    out=image2, casting='unsafe')
    return image2.astype(cp.uint8)

def lut_displaycp(image2, display_min, display_max) :
    lut = cp.arange(2**16, dtype='uint16')
    lut = displaycp(lut, display_min, display_max)
    return cp.take(lut, image2)

np.all(display(image, display_min, display_max) ==
           lut_display(image, display_min, display_max))

imagecp = cp.asarray(image)
type(imagecp)

cp.all(displaycp(imagecp, display_min, display_max) ==
           lut_displaycp(imagecp, display_min, display_max))

np.all(cp.asnumpy(displaycp(imagecp, display_min, display_max)) ==
          display(image, display_min, display_max))
```

Timings

```
timeit.timeit('display(image, display_min, display_max)',
                  'from __main__ import display, image, display_min, display_max',
                   number=100)
```

1.2715457340000285

```
timeit.timeit('lut_display(image, display_min, display_max)',
                  'from __main__ import lut_display, image, display_min, display_max',
                  number=100)
```

0.27357000399933895

```
timeit.timeit('displaycp(imagecp, display_min, display_max)',
                  'from __main__ import displaycp, imagecp, display_min, display_max',
                   number=100)
```

0.018452465999871492

```
timeit.timeit('lut_displaycp(imagecp, display_min, display_max)',
                  'from __main__ import lut_displaycp, imagecp, display_min, display_max',
                  number=100)
```

0.015030614999886893