# How do I change the element in the array according to a linear function in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to convert 16 bit int raw TIFF to 8 bit int png.
A step in that includes changing the values in an array from 0 - 4095 to 0 - 255.

example:

```
[0, 32, 64, ..., 4095] should be converted to: [0, 2, 4, ..., 255 ]
```

I know that this can be achieved with simple loop through all values in the array, but does numpy provide some standard function for this type of task? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485886/how-to-convert-a-16-bit-to-an-8-bit-image-in-opencv and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464449/using-numpy-to-efficiently-convert-16-bit-image-data-to-8-bit-for-display-with

Comment: Simply divide by `16` : `a//16`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply multiplying the array (image) by `float(255)/4095.0` won't do the trick?

Comment: Apologies. It works. At first, I read the image using `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`, so it did not work, but it works when I load using `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED`. Thank you so much - I'll delete the previous comment to avoid confusion to others. Thank you! :)